# R create a column by concatenating all other columns in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation

I have a data frame with say 20 columns, I would like to create another column that concatenates all other columns, is there a concise way to write the code without expicity writing out each column's column name?

For example my data call model_spec looks like:

[image]

this is my current solution:
it worked but the problem is that it's very hard=coded and what if I have 100 variables? is there way to achieve this automatically and concatenate all columns without ugly-looking code of explicitly writing out each column name? Thanks in advance! any advice or point to method/function is appreciated!

```
want = model_spec %>% mutate(
  model_formula = paste0('y ~' , var1 ,'+', var2, '+',var3,'+',var4,'+',var5,
                         '+',var6,'+',var7, '+',var8,'+',var9,'+',var10,
                         '+',var11,'+',var12,'+',var13,'+',var14,'+',var15,'+',var16,'+', 
                         var17,'+',var18, '+', var19, '+', var20))
  ) %>% select(model_id, model_formula)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  unite("new_col", var1:var6, na.rm=TRUE, sep = " + ") %>% 
  mutate(new_col = paste0("y ~ ", new_col))
```

```
  model_id                 new_col
1        1 y ~ gdp + ur + dpi + ir
2        1      y ~ ur + ltv + dti
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(model_id = c(1L, 1L), var1 = c("gdp", NA), var2 = c("ur", 
"ur"), var3 = c(NA, "ltv"), var4 = c("dpi", NA), var5 = c(NA, 
"dti"), var6 = c("ir", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: thanks a lot! that helps a lot!!!!!! may i ask is there a way to extend the code to an even more generalized version, when my variable names are not exactly in the form of var1, var2, var3...? for example, my variable names are  var_gpd, var_ur, var_dpi, var_ir....? because that's the problem I'm facing. I wrote it in the original post to make it shorter, but in real data I get, I don't know how to extend code to allow for other name formats. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: We could use `starts_with("var")` instead of `var1:var6`.

Comment: omg, thanks a lot. I really need to expand my R knowledge. appreciate it!!!